# Scope of DEFINE variable in php

Tags: php, variables

Just a quick questions please, that I can't find the answer to.

If I define a variable like the below example:

```
DEFINE('THIS_TEST', 'ABC');
```

What is the scope of this? Could I then use this with in a class/object function:

```
public function testFunction() {
    echo THIS_TEST;
}
```

I have tried this in something similar but am not getting the results I was expecting, although this could be related to other issues.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What results do you get?

Comment: i am using it as a EMAIL_FROM for phpmailer (extended), but the email is not being sent. so i wondered if the defined variable was available to the function without injecting it... and a quick google for the scope did not answer my question

Comment: I'll bet you're probably getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC...` right? Remove the "public". Your code checks out without the "public" but threw the error when included.

Comment: That issue is not caused by this. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail) for troubleshooting tips.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, i am being lazy and have not got as far as looking the errors yet as i started to wonder (wanted to learn) the scope of a DEFINE variable first... + i only included an example which includes the "public function..." this is of course wrapped in a class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read about scoping [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

> Like superglobals, the scope of a constant is global. You can access
>   constants anywhere in your script without regard to scope. For more
>   information on scope, read the manual section on variable scope.

Comment: thanks, thats what i was looking for, could not find it for some reason.... its late here

Comment: yep, i also ran my own test too, but thought i would ask here as i could not find the details and find it better to know why things work rather than just knowing they do....

Comment: Can you `define()` inside a class? Will it be accessive only via `$class_name->CONSTANT_NAME` or will it be super global? Also can you conditionally `define()` inside an `If` statement?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you actually mean the lowercase `define()`, this defines a **constant** (not a variable), which is available globally (with the exception of namespaces):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: thanks, thats what i was looking for, could not find it for some reason.... probably as my inexperience called it a "defined variable" and not a constant. thanks!